# D'Alembert operator interaction term in QFT Lagrangian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, fourier-transform, feynman-diagrams, interactions

I'm trying to understand how to find the Feynman rules (and use them to calculate loop diagrams) for this Lagrangian (found on the [Saclay lectures](https://userswww.pd.infn.it/%7Eferuglio/Falkowski.pdf)):
$$\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}_\text{kin}-\frac{\tilde{C_4}}{4!}\phi^4-\frac{\tilde{C_6}}{4!M^2}\phi^3\square\phi.\tag{2.6}$$
Now, the only thing I know about derivative interactions is that, when writing a field in momentum space, one has a $e^{ipx}$ factor, and so a term like $\partial^\mu\phi$ becomes $(ip^\mu)$ in the Feynman rule. Since here there is a $\partial^\mu\partial_\mu\phi=\square\phi$ term, I expect the Feynman diagram to be modified by $(-p^2)$. This should be everything, because the numerical factor should still be $4!$ (I have 4 fields that can all be the "derivate one", and once that's chose, I have a $3!$ factor for the other 3 fields).
So my rules would be:
$$\phi^4\longrightarrow-i\tilde{C_4}$$
$$\phi^3\square\phi\longrightarrow i\tilde{C_6}\frac{p^2}{M^2}$$

Something tells me that I'm wrong, because the 1-loop correction to the propagator is written as
$$-\tilde{C_4}\text{(integral of propagator)}+\frac{\tilde{C_6}}{4M^2}2(k^2+m^2)\text{(integral of propagator)}\tag{2.21}$$
Why are there the "2" and "4" factors? But most importantly, **how can the mass $m^2$ be there?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he has a typo in $(2.21)$. In the first line the $m^2$ at the numerator of the second integral should actually be a $p^2$. You can see that in the second line a $p^2$ appears out of nowhere.

Anyway, the derivative is only acting on one field, so the $p^2$ in the Feynman rule is the momentum of one of the legs. When you take the momentum of the two legs that enter in the loop, you will get the $k^2$ terms, while when you take the momentum of the external legs you will get the $p^2$. The factor $2$ comes from the fact that you have $4$ legs, two internal and two external.

EDIT: for clarification, the full Feynman Rule is

$$\phi^3\square\phi\to -3!(p_1^2+p_2^2+p_3^2+p_4^2) $$

where $p_i$ is the momentum of the $i$ leg.

Comment: And what about the factor $4$ in the denominator? Is it another symmetry factor?

Comment: @MauroGiliberti When you compute the Feynman rule of that operator you get a $3!$ from the three non-differentiated fields, so you are left with a $1/4$ from the $1/4!$ of the definition of the operator that is not cancelled.

Comment: But shouldn't one also consider that the differentiated field can be chosen as one of 4 fields, so a factor of $1/4$? Or is the differentiated field "different" from the others in that when I compute the Feynman rule, I have to treat it like another, separate, field?

Comment: @MauroGiliberti The fact that you can choose the differentiated field in 4 ways is what afterwards gives you the $2(k^2+p^2)$. I have added the full Feynman rule to the answer, maybe that's more clear